# react redux добавление в корзину

Tags: reactjs, redux

я делаю интернет магазин, у меня в state есть массив items это все значения, которые я получаю по api в общем все товары так же у меня есть отдельный редьюсер для корзины и там есть массив itemsInCart

```
let initialState = {
    itemsInCart: [],
}
```

если я добавляю один предмет в корзину, всё хорошо, но если я добавлю ещё один так же у меня он добавляется другой позицией, а должен бы просто увеличиваться счётчик кол-во товара по этой позиции, подскажите как правильно делать нужно наверное какой-то словарь типа Map создавать вместо массива itemsInCart: [] или это можно сделать как-то иначе?
вот case из reducer где я добавляю один товар к массиву, в котором находятся товары в корзине, а как ещё хранить их количество?

```
case Add_To_Cart:
    return{
        ...state,
        itemsInCart: [...state.itemsInCart, action.payload]
    }
```

Comment: Есть ссылка на проект на GitHub ?

Comment: да https://github.com/AnotherSidePhobos/GunStore